# How can I get the current clusters' markers on google map using MarkerCluster.js

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

My situation is that I have lots of geo data, and many of them have same lat & long.

I want to keep MarkerCluster's zoomOnClick handler alive, but when the map keep zoom in and got max zoom level, the same lat&long data in a cluster won't be separated(cause reach the max zoom level which is 21) <-- that's make sense.
So, all I want to do is when map got max zoom level, I click the clustermarker, I don't zoom in, I want to pop up a info window to show all the markers' info in that cluster.

I can click the clustermarker and pop up a info window right now( by modify the MarkerCluster.js), but I don't know how to get those markers in that clustermarker, for now, I only can got all markers return...

Does anyone know how to do this or how should I modify the js file?
Or maybe someone have same scenario, too?

It would be appreciated for any advice, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To get the current(clicked) cluster, access the argument passed to the `clusterclick`-callback.

The method `getMarkers()` of this argument will return an array which contains the markers in the cluster, loop over the array and collect your desired data.

**Note:** I don't know which version of markerclusterer.js you use, my answer refers to [this version](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js) .
There is also no need to modify this version, all of your requested features may be reached without any modifications.

Short example of how to access the markers:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markerclustererObject,'clusterclick',
   function(clickedCluster){
   console.log(clickedCluster.getMarkers());
});
```

Comment: I use the same version of markercluster.js with you, and the things that I don't know is "how could I get the current cluster I clicked without modify anythings?" 
Is there any method I can called? I didn't find that..
and when I console.log the getMarkers() method in zoomOnClick() function, it prints all markers in all cluster instead of markers in the cluster I clicked on it.

hope you can understand what I mean.. I'm not good at explain sort of things in english..

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have two questions, one is that I saw 'clusterclick' in markercluster.js is deprecated name, is it suitable for using this?

Another question is different from this one, so I will post a new one for that.

Comment: When you mean this file: http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/trunk/markerclustererplus/src/markerclusterer.js?r=362#151 , this is another library(markerClustererPlus), based on markerClusterer . In this library clusterclick is deprecated, but not in the original marcerclusterer.js(where a click-event doesn't exist for a cluster)